# SQL server FileTable partitioning

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I'm a beginner at SQL servers, and would like to ask something to the pros as I'm not 100% sure of the answer. Is it really not possible to partition a FileTable?

Answer (score 1):

No, [partitioning is NOT supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492086.aspx) for FileTable.

> **Partitioning is not supported on FileTables.** With the support for multiple FILESTREAM file groups, pure scale-up issues can be handled without having to resort to partitioning in most scenarios (unlike SQL 2008 FILESTREAMs).